# Getting attributes of td with multiple classes

Tags: jquery, html

Iam using an event calendar. In this i want to take the attributes of the `td`

```
<td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-18"></td>
```

I want to take the `data-date`'s attribute value from the `td` with class `fc-day`. The other class `fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past` changes inorder with each date.I tried to take the attribute value using the jquery `$('.fc-day').attr('data-date');` but not workin.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `attr("data-date")` should work. Are you sure the DOM is ready when you perform that call?

Answer (score 5):

use `.data()`:

```
$('.fc-day').data('date')
```

Using `.each()`:

```
$('.fc-day').each(function(){
  alert($(this).data('date'));
});
```

Comment: Would there be a situation this would work if `.attr("data-date")` didn't?

Comment: Can you provide an example where `.attr()` doesn't work and `.data()` work. In context of problem

Comment: $( document ).ready(function() {
var val=$('.fc-day').data('data-date');
});

not working

Comment: @user3332783, `var val=$('.fc-day').data('date')`

Comment: @user3332783 You can't put this in `document.ready`. You need to wait for FullCalendar to be ready. Use http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewRender/

Comment: Iam getting only one date.Actually ihave more td vals like <td class="fc-day fc-tue fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-11">
<td class="fc-day fc-wed fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-12">
<td class="fc-day fc-thu fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-13">
<td class="fc-day fc-fri fc-widget-content fc-past" data-date="2014-02-14">

Comment: you need to iterate for all elements using `.each()`. and then get using `$(this).data('date')` inside